# How to merge two objects which have same property name

Tags: javascript

I would like to merge two objects into one which have same property name.
For example,

```
var a = {
            "user-activity":{
                "name":"INPUT - radio",
                "value":"radio - No"
            }
        };
var b = {
            "user-activity":{
                "name":"INPUT - radio",
                "value":"radio - No"
            }
        };
var c = a.concat(b);
```

I am expecting output like below.

```
{
    "user-activity":{
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                    },
    "user-activity":{
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                    }
};
```

And not like below.

```
[{
     "user-activity":{
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                        }
},{
     "user-activity":{
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                        }
}]
```

Comment: You can't have two keys with the same name. How would you be able to select them later?

Comment: `expecting` the impossible

Comment: @JJJ: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX: I understood now. Thank you!

Comment: Having same properties name in not possible.

Comment: `keys` are like `primary keys` in database - it needs to be unique. In all languages that have hash map data-structure this will be like this only. Also I guess you need to merge them, it is the same value.

Comment: Also concat does not create an object but an array (or a string if you are calling it on strings)

Comment: @Nishant: Thanks Nishant. Please mention the same under answer so that i can mark this as correct answer.

Comment: Lastly I would think most people would want `{
    "user-activity":{ "a": {
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                    },
    "b":{
                        "name":"INPUT - radio",
                        "value":"radio - No"
                    }
};` when they combined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Keys` are like `Primary Keys` / `Unique ID`s in database to draw an analogy - it needs to be unique because of the way it is implemented. `Keys` are the important thing, which identifies a value. All languages that have [hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically) data structures it will be like this only.

Also in your use case, I guess you need to merge them, it is the same value.

You can also check this [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicate property names in an object is in no way possible. 
Probably you need to rethink the scenario where you need to have a solution like this and figure out some alternate solution.